# Unable to create object in C++

Tags: c++, class, object, pointer-to-pointer

I've been trying to solve a Graph problem & the teacher gave me this code. I don't know how to run it.
My code is:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

#define White 0
#define Gray 2
#define Black 3

int row, col;
int **Graph;

class Graph
{
private:
    bool** adjacencyMatrix;
    int vertexCount;
public:

    Graph(int vertexCount)
    {

        this->vertexCount = vertexCount;
        adjacencyMatrix = new bool*[vertexCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
        {
            adjacencyMatrix[i] = new bool[vertexCount];
            for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
                adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = false;
        }
    }

    Graph(char filename[], int vertexCount)
    {

        this->vertexCount = vertexCount;
        adjacencyMatrix = new bool*[vertexCount];

        ifstream file;
        file.open(filename, ios::in);

        if( !file)
        {
            cout << "\nError: Cannot open file\n";
            return;
        }

        if(file.is_open())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
            {

                adjacencyMatrix[i] = new bool[vertexCount];

                for (int j = 0; j < vertexCount; j++)
                    file>>adjacencyMatrix[i][j];
            }
        }
    }


    ~Graph()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
            delete[] adjacencyMatrix[i];
        delete[] adjacencyMatrix;
    }

    void runDFS(int u, int state[])
    {

        state[u] = Gray;

        for (int v = 0; v < vertexCount; v++)

            if (isEdge(u, v) && state[v] == White)

                runDFS(v, state);

        state[u] = Black;
        cout<<u<<",";
    }

    void DFS()
    {

        int *state = new int[vertexCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < vertexCount; i++)
            state[i] = White;

        runDFS(0, state);

        delete [] state;

    }

    void display()
    {

        int u,v;

        for(u=0; u<vertexCount; ++u)
        {
            cout << "\nadj[" << (char) (u+65) << "] -> ";
            for(v=0; v<vertexCount; ++v)
            {
                cout << " " << adjacencyMatrix[u][v];
            }
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

    bool isEdge(int i, int j)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < vertexCount && j > 0 && j < vertexCount)
            return adjacencyMatrix[i][j];
        else
            return false;
    }

    void removeEdge(int i, int j)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < vertexCount && j > 0 && j < vertexCount)
        {
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = false;
            adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = false;
        }
    }

    void addEdge(int i, int j)
    {
        if (i >= 0 && i < vertexCount && j > 0 && j < vertexCount)
        {
            adjacencyMatrix[i][j] = true;
            adjacencyMatrix[j][i] = true;
        }
    }
};


int main()
{
    Graph = new int*[row];
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        Graph[i] = new int[col];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            Graph[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    Graph A = new Graph("Hello.txt", 2); //This line is showing the error

}
```

but it is showing me the error:

```
D:\Fayaz\Undirected graph.cpp|157|error: expected ';' before 'A'|
```

Can anyone please tell me how to create a Graph class's object and use its functions/methods?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: In your main A must be a pointer.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate the code? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Graph* A = new Graph("Hello.txt", 2);

Comment: Tried Graph* A = new Graph("Hello.txt", 2); and its showing this error: D:\Fayaz\Undirected graph.cpp|157|error: 'A' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: To learn C++ effectively you need to abandon using C-style pointer arrays and instead use the Standard Library tools like `std::vector`.

Comment: @tadman definetly I will post in my answer a more correct answer.

Comment: Those `#define` constants are also crying out for a simple `enum`.

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are a match made in hell. Be really careful with that combination.

Comment: If you're trying to solve graph problems, but you can't quite figure out how to get your code to compile correctly, you should probably be spending some time in TA hours to catch back up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pseudo-corrected version of your code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

enum class BWColor
{
    White,
    Gray,
    Black
};

class Graph
{
private:
    std::map<int, std::vector<int>>         graph;
    int                                     vertexCount;

private:
    void dfs(std::vector<BWColor>& visit, int u)
    {
        std::cout << u << " ";
        visit[u] = BWColor::Gray;

        for(std::vector<int>::iterator it = graph[u].begin(); it != graph[u].end(); ++it)
        {
            if(visit[*it] == BWColor::White)
            {
                dfs(visit, *it);
            }
        }

        visit[u] = BWColor::Black;
    }

public:
    Graph(int vertexCount) : vertexCount(vertexCount) {}

    Graph(const char* filename, int vertexCount) : Graph(vertexCount)
    {
        std::ifstream file;
        file.open(filename, std::ios::in);

        if(!file)
        {
            std::cerr << "Error: Cannot open file\n";
            return;
        }

        if(file.is_open())
        {
            int k = 0;
            int u = -1;

            while(file >> k)
            {
                ++u;

                if(k == 0)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                graph[u / vertexCount].push_back(u % vertexCount);
            }
        }
    }


    ~Graph() {}

    void runDFS(int u)
    {
        std::vector<BWColor> visit(vertexCount, BWColor::White);
        dfs(visit, u);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Graph& g);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Graph& g)
{
    for(std::map<int, std::vector<int>>::const_iterator it = g.graph.cbegin(); it != g.graph.cend(); ++it)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < it->second.size(); ++i)
        {
            stream << '(' << it->first << ", " << it->second[i] << ")\n"; 
        }
    }

    return stream;
}

int main()
{
    Graph gA("graph.txt", 4);
    std::cout << gA << "DFS: {";
    gA.runDFS(2);
    std::cout << "}\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```

Here are some advices:

- Prefer STL containers (safer) rather than C-style ones;
- Use the stack every time you can (new and delete are costly). Thus forgetting to delete an object will lead to a memory leak

I am loading the following adjacency matrix with the second constructor, `Graph(const char* filename, int vertexCount)`:

> ```
> 0 1 0 0
> 0 0 1 0
> 1 0 0 1
> 0 0 1 1
> ```

Then, I translate the adjacency matrix into a collection of arcs `uv`, represented by the `std::map<int, std::vector<int>> graph;` private member.

Finally, I proceed to DFS.

Comment: Thanks in advance... ^_^

Comment: Could you show me just an extract of your files (those representing a graph I suppose) please?